# Wireless network adapter stays hard blocked

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, atheros

I recently installed Ubuntu for the first time and I really like it. But there is one problem I can't get rid off: my wireless adapter stays harblocked. So the option enable wifi in the network menu remains grayed out and I can't find the router where my laptop stands next to.

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I tried ublocking it, on the command line and on my keyboard (FN+f2 did the trick in W8) but nothing seems to affect it.

my network card:

```
$ lspci | grep Wireless
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

some other information:

```
$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        24:FD:52:C5:CC:B5

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points
```

**lshw -class network**

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 24:fd:52:c5:cc:b5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.11.0-15-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
```

**Uname**

```
$ uname -a
Linux brecht-laptop 3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I also tried adding a file named ath9k.conf in /etc/modprobe.d/ with some options in it but still no results. I also tried some other things I read on google without even knowing well what I was doing but nothing seems to help.

So can someone help me out with this? I really like Linux but this is an unfortunate hiccup.

**Update:** I found out that my wifi works just fine if I close my laptop and reopen it (so after going to sleep mode or whatever it's called in Linux). But this is not the perfect solution I guess.

Comment: Have a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1234469 - it *might* be the same issue. ( https://www.google.com/search?q=networkmanager+suspend+hard+block also shows the same issue from other distros using NetworkManager and might also contain useful hints)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the link you send me doesn't work for me. In this topic, people lose there connection after hibernation, I have only connection after my laptop went in hibernation. It's like  an opposite problem

Comment: OMFG. Thanks a lot. I'm on this problem since a few hours now, and I finaly find the answer. Your config is exactly the same than mine. And I tried what you said : "Close the laptop, and re-open it", and it works ! Sorry if my english is not great. I'm french. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. WiFi starts working after closing and re-opening the lid. It seems that the problem is only with some Asus laptops (mine is X551C)

In [one of the articles I found](https://medium.com/@thechiefalone/atheros-ar9485-wireless-network-adapter-problem-solved-e8b8b7f5848a) there is also a modprobe setting added:

```
echo “options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```